# React checkbox not initialy taking value of object

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, state

I have a project where I need to use a checkbox. My data comes from a database and gets injected in an state object. This object contains a list of children and each child contains a boolean called 'xmasCamp2019'. But the first time this code gets rendered the checkbox doesn't take over the value of the boolean.

But when I do a log of the boolean it outputs true. When the onChange is called the boolean of that child is swapped and then the checkbox does gets checked.

```
{this.state.selectedRegistration.childrenArray.map((child) => {
            console.log(child.xmasCamp2019);
            return (
              <FormControlLabel
                key={child.index}
                value={child.xmasCamp2019}
                onChange={(event, value) =>
                  this.selectChild(child.index, value)
                }
                control={
                  <Checkbox name="Insurance" value={child.xmasCamp2019} />
                }
                label={child.name}
              />
            );
          })}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does the `<Checkbox />` component look like? Checkboxes in react use the checked attribute for storing boolean state, example `<input type="checkbox" checked={xmasCamp2019} />`

Comment: Thank you. I thought it was the value that needed to be set in stead of checked.